# Error while using create-react-app

Tags: command-line, nodejs, npm

During an attempt to install create-react-app on my os (unbuntu 22.04), I got this output from the terminal.

```
t*****@poudlardo:~$ sudo npm -g install create-react-app
ERROR: npm v9.6.4 is known not to run on Node.js v12.22.9.  This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.

ERROR:
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/exit-handler.js:19
  const hasLoadedNpm = npm?.config.loaded
                           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js:42:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:2:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
```

Please know that I already tried several times to install / update npm, nodejs or react. That's why I don't even understand the first error about node supported version.

```
    t*****@poudlardo:~$ node -v
    v18.16.0

    t*****@poudlardo:~$ npm -v
    9.6.6
```

How can I install create-react-app ?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu version of 22.03 please correct.

Comment: my bad, corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

To create a new React project, we can use the tool npx, provided you have an npm version of at least 5.2.

`npx create-react-app my-react-app`